FastAPI, SQLAlchemy , asyncio, This session is provisioning a new connection; concurrent operations are not permitted
connection.py
from typing import AsyncIterable
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy import NullPool

SessionFactoryType = async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]

def create_session_factory(connection_url: str, **kwargs: dict[str, ...]) -> async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]:
    async_engine = create_async_engine(url=connection_url, **kwargs, poolclass=NullPool)
    return async_sessionmaker(async_engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)

async def create_async_session(session_factory: SessionFactoryType) -> AsyncIterable[AsyncSession]:
    async with session_factory() as session:
        yield session

unit_of_work.py
import contextlib
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, AsyncSessionTransaction
from src.common.interfaces.unit_of_work import AbstractUnitOfWork

class SQLAlchemyUnitOfWork(AbstractUnitOfWork[AsyncSession, AsyncSessionTransaction]):
    async def commit(self) -> None:
        with contextlib.suppress(SQLAlchemyError):
            await self.session.commit()

    async def rollback(self) -> None:
        with contextlib.suppress(SQLAlchemyError):
            await self.session.rollback()

    async def create_transaction(self) -> None:
        if not self.session.in_transaction() and self.session.is_active:
            self._transaction = await self.session.begin()

    async def close_transaction(self) -> None:
        if self.session.is_active and not self.session.in_transaction():
            await self.session.close()

def unit_of_work_factory(session: AsyncSession) -> SQLAlchemyUnitOfWork:
    return SQLAlchemyUnitOfWork(session=session)

crud.py
from typing import Any, Mapping, Optional, Sequence, TypeVar
from iotsota_models.orm import BaseSQLAlchemyModel
from sqlalchemy import ColumnExpressionArgument, insert, select, update
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from src.common.interfaces.crud import AbstractCRUDRepository

ModelType = TypeVar("ModelType", bound=BaseSQLAlchemyModel)

class SQLAlchemyCRUDRepository(AbstractCRUDRepository[ModelType, ColumnExpressionArgument]):
    __slots__ = ("_session",)

    def __init__(self, session: AsyncSession, model: type[ModelType]) -> None:
        super().__init__(model)
        self._session = session

    async def select(self, *clauses: ColumnExpressionArgument) -> ModelType | None:
        stmt = select(self.model).where(*clauses)
        return (await self._session.execute(stmt)).scalars().first()

    async def select_many(
        self, *clauses: ColumnExpressionArgument, offset: Optional[int] = None, limit: Optional[int] = None
    ) -> Sequence[ModelType]:
        stmt = select(self.model).where(*clauses).offset(offset).limit(limit)
        return (await self._session.execute(stmt)).scalars().all()

    async def create(self, **values: Mapping[str, Any]) -> ModelType | None:
        stmt = insert(self.model).values(**values).returning(self.model)
        return (await self._session.execute(stmt)).scalars().first()

    async def update(self, *clauses: ColumnExpressionArgument, **values: Mapping[str, Any]) -> list[ModelType] | None:
        stmt = update(self.model).where(*clauses).values(**values).returning(self.model)
        return (await self._session.execute(stmt)).unique().scalars().all()

Traceback
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Documents/WORK/authentication-service/src/databases/orm/repositories/user/reader.py", line 13, in select_user
    return await self.repository.crud.select(clauses)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Documents/WORK/authentication-service/src/databases/orm/repositories/crud.py", line 21, in select
    return (await self._session.execute(stmt)).scalars().first()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth_service-v_N9SFpi-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 461, in execute
    result = await greenlet_spawn(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth_service-v_N9SFpi-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 190, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth_service-v_N9SFpi-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2306, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth_service-v_N9SFpi-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2181, in _execute_internal
    conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth_service-v_N9SFpi-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2050, in _connection_for_bind
    return trans._connection_for_bind(engine, execution_options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth_service-v_N9SFpi-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 103, in _go
    self._raise_for_prerequisite_state(fn.__name__, current_state)
  File "/Users/oleksiiyudin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth_service-v_N9SFpi-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 945, in _raise_for_prerequisite_state
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is provisioning a new connection; concurrent operations are not permitted (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/isce)

Versions:
Python  "^3.12"
sqlalchemy  "^2.0.29"
asyncpg  "^0.29.0"
greenlet  "^3.0.3"
I encountered a problem when working with asynchronous database queries, even when reading. The service on fastapi occasionally gets this error, so everything may be fine for a while.

That's  lot of code. Can you reduce it to the minimum required to reproduce the problem (see [mre])?
